# How to move objects on the screen

Tags: java, swing, animation

Hi can anybody please guide me about how to move objects on the screen.Have          tried
but its not working. My code draws a 100 ovals on the screen,what do i need     to get these oval to move.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;


public class DropGui extends JFrame {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int xpos,ypos,xvel,yvel,size;

    public DropGui()
    {
        setTitle("Testing Moving Objects");
        setSize(900,600);
        setLocation(200,80);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        // assign random values to xpos,ypos,size variables
         xpos = rand.nextInt(900 - 0 + 1) + 0; 
         ypos = rand.nextInt(900 - 0 + 1) + 0; 
         size = rand.nextInt(30 - 5 + 1) + 5; 

    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        // draws about a 100 ovals to the screen
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
        {
            g.fillOval(xpos,ypos,size,size);   

            xpos = rand.nextInt(900 - 0 + 1) + 0; 
            ypos = rand.nextInt(900 - 0 + 1) + 0; 
            size = rand.nextInt(30 - 5 + 1) + 5; 
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't override paint().

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel (or JComponent) and then you add the panel to the frame. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step1.html) for more information and examples.

Also, you should not be generating random objects in a painting method. You can't control when the painting method is invoked. Instead you should create a List of objects you want to paint and then the painting method will iterate through this list to paint all the objects. See the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example of how to implement this.

Finally, if you want animation then you should use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the animation. When the Timer fires you iterate through the List and change the location of every object in the List. Then you invoke `repaint()` on the panel so the objects can be repainted.